# select first n items of a list without using a loop.

Tags: python, list

I know I can do this with a loop but I was wondering if there was a neater solution?

I have a list, which I want to select the first n items and place them in another list.

What I want to do is something like (pseudo code)

```
n = 3

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

y = copy n from x

print(y)

>>> [1,2,3]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116) like this

```
y = x[:n]
print(y)
```

When you say `x[:n]`, it means that, get all the elements till index `n` (but not including the element at index `n`).